# Rails 5 error with nested_attributes for a has_one relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm able to get a model Post to be working properly for `has_many` and `accepts_nested_attributes_for` model Category. However, I want to limit a post to have only 1 category, which is where I'm failing. Here is the revised code:

```
# post.rb
has_one :category_tag, :dependent => :delete
has_one :category, through: :category_tag
accepts_nested_attributes_for :category_tag

# posts_controller.rb
def new
  @post = Post.new
  @post.category_tag.build
end
```

And ^ there is the problem: **undefined method 'build' for nil:NilClass**
It worked fine when I was using `has_many :category_tags` in the model and `@post.category_tags.build`
TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `has_one` relationships the correct format is

```
@post.build_category_tag
```

Comment: I'm using rails 5 and the solution sounded weird to me, indeed it isn't working.. `undefined method build_category_tag`

Comment: This is very strange! I switched back to `has_many` settings to continue working on other aspects of the app. However when you posted the answer(which didn't work), I tried the original line(after switching to has_one settings) `@post.category_tag.build` again and it worked flawlessly. I remember I did restart the server(which shouldn't be a problem in the first place) when I was trying what I posted.

Comment: It should've been created.  See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-one-association-reference

Comment: And the guide specifically says you should not use @post.category_tag.build in `has_one` because it can lead to orphaned records.

Comment: I read everything you pointed out. However I'm unable to debug the cause of problem. Can you guide me somehow?

Comment: I must be doing something wrong. Sorry for the trouble, it worked. Also, thanks for pointing out the `has_many` part in the guide.